# Can't use `od` command with directories

Tags: osx, od

I'm trying to use the `od` command in a directory in OSX but it doesn't proceed and it results in the error message:

```
od: .: Is a directory
```

Could you please help me with it or any equivalent command?

Comment: Related: [When did directories stop being readable as files?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/154119/80216)

Comment: Why are you trying to do a hex dump of a directory?

Comment: I'm just trying to look at the i-node numbers of a directory as a part of understanding how the directory is implemented in the system. I'm following it in the book "the UNIX programming environment"

Answer (score 0):

As @G-Man commented, you [ can't read directories as file [When did directories stop being readable as files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/154119/80216]);

Instead, to find i-node numbers, you could use

```
stat
```

```
➜  stat -x .
  File: "."
  Size: 1632         FileType: Directory
  Mode: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)         Uid: (  501/  barisa)  Gid: (   20/   staff)
Device: 1,2   Inode: 5431597    Links: 48
Access: Sun Dec 14 15:17:23 2014
Modify: Sun Dec 14 14:16:25 2014
Change: Sun Dec 14 14:16:25 2014
```