# How to see information inside inode data structure

Tags: files, filesystems, inode

I can do an `ls -li` to see a file's inode number, but how can I list information inside a particular inode by using that inode number.

Comment: Plain `ls -l`? What information are you after exactly?

Comment: Ok i just tried the stat command on the file name , and most of the information an inode contains is reported by stat command

Comment: See this excellent answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216644/simple-way-to-see-the-content-of-directories-in-linux-unix-file-systems/216664#216664

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have a ext2/3/4 filesystem you can use `debugfs` for a low-level look at an inode. For example, to play without being root:

```
$ truncate -s 1M myfile
$ mkfs.ext2 -F myfile
$ debugfs -w myfile
debugfs:  stat <2>
    Inode: 2   Type: directory    Mode:  0755   Flags: 0x0
    Generation: 0    Version: 0x00000000
    User:     0   Group:     0   Size: 1024
    File ACL: 0    Directory ACL: 0
    Links: 3   Blockcount: 2
    Fragment:  Address: 0    Number: 0    Size: 0
    ctime: 0x5722081d -- Thu Apr 28 14:54:53 2016
    atime: 0x5722081d -- Thu Apr 28 14:54:53 2016
    mtime: 0x5722081d -- Thu Apr 28 14:54:53 2016
    BLOCKS:
    (0):24
    TOTAL: 1
```

The command `stat` takes a inode number inside `<>`.

Answer (score 7):

You can find inode information using `stat` command.

```
# stat myfile.txt
  File: myfile.txt
  Size: 2023        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd03h/64771d    Inode: 15997895    Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/   antop)   Gid: ( 1000/   antop)
Context: unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0
Access: 2019-08-30 08:29:16.974661276 +0530
Modify: 2019-08-30 08:29:16.974661276 +0530
Change: 2019-08-30 08:29:16.974661276 +0530
Birth: 2019-08-30 08:29:16.974661276 +0530
```

[a detailed note on inode, hardlink & softlink](https://coffeewithbytes.com/blog/hardlink_softlink/)

Answer (score 1):

an inode wil store only one file. try

```
find /xxx -xdev -inum 1234 -print
```

where

- `/xxx` is mounting point
- `-inum 1234` search for an inode number 1234
- `-print` self explainatory

This suppose /xxx is mounted an healthy.

Comment: Not quite what is requested in the question but still was useful in educational purpose. Thanks.