# Can we use read(), write() on a directory in unix/linux?

Tags: directory, read, write

Can we use `read()`, `write()` on a directory just like on any other file in Unix/Linux? I have a confusion here because directories are also considered as files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does one inspect the directory structure information of a unix/linux file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178651/how-does-one-inspect-the-directory-structure-information-of-a-unix-linux-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some filesystems allow to use `read()` on directories, but this must be seen as a mistake since the data structures in such a directory may be undocumented.

You never can use `write()` since this would destroy the integrity of the affected directory.

The official interfaces for directories are `opendir(), closedir() readdir(), telldir(), seekdir()`

Answer (score 1):

not really, no, there are dedicated

```
directory, opendir, closedir, dirfd, fdopendir, readdir, readdir_r,
  rewinddir, seekdir, telldir(3) - directory operations
```

functions for operations on directories (those are from OpenBSD) and modern filesystems (or really anything in decade or two or more) in no way encode directories as plain files.

Answer (score 0):

I have a book from 1986 that cites using `read()` for reading dirctories.
It's named *The Design Of The UNIX Operating System* and this use is mentioned on page 10, but this code does not work on my modern Ubuntu.

Asking around Google and GPT it seems that at 1988 there was already a dedicated `readdir()` function, so that has changed.