# How to create directory and files inside the directory

Tags: linux, files, directory-structure, mkdir, touch

I want to know how to place files using touch command inside an directory whether it is multiple or single file.help is appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does one inspect the directory structure information of a unix/linux file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178651/how-does-one-inspect-the-directory-structure-information-of-a-unix-linux-file)

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer

```bsh
mkdir -p mydir/{colors,shape,animals}

mkdir -p mydir/colors/{basic,blended}
touch mydir/colors/basic/{red,blue,green}
touch mydir/colors/blended/{yellow,orange,pink}
touch mydir/shape/{circle,square,cube}

mkdir -p mydir/animals/{mammals,reptiles} 
touch mydir/animals/mammals/{platypus,bat,dog}
touch mydir/animals/reptiles/{snakes,crocodile,lizard}
```